# What is the best architecture and table design for a chat application with the use of Cassandra and trigger

Tags: triggers, cassandra, chat

I want to leverage the use of trigger to make push to different users when a message is sent.

Comment: I think, is not very good idea. If I send message and trigger will write it to table, how my companion will recieve it? I will be better to use other mechanism for delivery messages and write to Cassandra only history of chat

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Sabik about not using a trigger to deliver the messages, should be better to handle within your application.

If you want to store the chat history, you might try something like below.

Considering chat will be same for both users, we only want to store once so will have an ID for each chat. We can have a separate table to store all the chats a user is involved with. This will allow extension to group chats with more than 2 users.

This is a quick example but then you might look at enhancements to try to do things like order the user's chats based on most recent message, etc.

```
CREATE TABLE chatsPerUser (
"user1" uuid,
"chatID" uuid,
PRIMARY KEY ("user1")
);

//Add any other metadata you need 
CREATE TABLE chat (
"chatID" uuid,
ts timestamp,
userID uuid,
message text,
PRIMARY KEY (("chatID"),ts)
);
```